# How to setup Python import for shared/common/utility project

Tags: python

I have a python module which contains shared utility code that I want to execute from other  python modules, it is called "common_test" because I am trying to test how to have common/shared code in python between projects.

Here is the layout of the common_test directory:

[image]

Here is the code in the 2 .py files:

fruit_messages.py

```
def appleMessage():
    return "Apples are expensive"
```

console_log.py

```
import src.utils.messages.fruit_messages as msgs

def logSomething():
    return print(msgs.appleMessage() + " all the time")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logSomething()
```

When I directly run the module console_log it works and I get this output:

```
(D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\common_test) D:\devs\my_ID\projects\common_test>python -m src.utils.log_mgmt.console_log
Apples are expensive all the time
```

I push this project to a git repo.

I have another project which tries to use the utility methods called "call_common". The structure is:
[image]

The code in top_level.py is:

```
import utils.log_mgmt.console_log as myLogger

myLogger.logSomething()
```

I install the pip dependency in another project with command:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.<removed>.com.au/ADRA/testcommonmodules/common_test
```

The pip install works and I see files added to:

```
D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\Lib\site-packages
```

```
D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\Lib\site-packages\utils>dir /s

 Directory of D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\Lib\site-packages\utils
13/07/2021  10:11 PM    <DIR>          log_mgmt
13/07/2021  10:11 PM    <DIR>          messages
13/07/2021  10:11 PM                 0 __init__.py

 Directory of D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\Lib\site-packages\utils\log_mgmt
13/07/2021  10:11 PM               178 console_log.py
13/07/2021  10:11 PM                 0 __init__.py

 Directory of D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\Lib\site-packages\utils\messages
13/07/2021  10:11 PM                54 fruit_messages.py
13/07/2021  10:11 PM                 0 __init__.py
```

When I run top_level.py it fails:

```
(D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common) D:\devs\GNYMWQ\projects\call_common>python -m top_level
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\devs\myID\projects\call_common\top_level.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utils.log_mgmt.console_log as myLogger
  File "D:\devs\myID\conda_envs\call_common\lib\site-packages\utils\log_mgmt\console_log.py", line 1, in <module>
    import src.utils.messages.fruit_messages as msgs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I see that the issue is due to the fully qualified import package statement within console_log.py which starts with "src":

```
import src.utils.messages.fruit_messages as msgs
```

It makes sense that this fails because if I directly edit this file in the location where it was placed by pip and remove the "src." from the start of the import statement to have the following it then works:

```
import utils.messages.fruit_messages as msgs
```

My problem is I seem to need the "src." on the import statement to allow my shared utils to call parts of itself, but I need to remove the "src." to allow modules that imported the shared utils to call it.

I am not locked into this structure, this is just my best attempt at achieving the following basic requirements:

1. creating a python shared utility project for internal use in my place of work
2. allowing the utility project to be hosted on gitlab
3. allowing other projects to use the features in the shared utility project
4. allowing the shared utility project to have unit tests

I am using latest versions of python, pip and anaconda.

Comment: why do you like `python -m somemodule `to execute script, rather than`python somefile.py`?

Comment: Both options give me the same result.

Comment: A lib should have its unique module name(or namespace), your module name starts with a common `utils` is also a very bad thing. you can use absolute path when installed the lib, or relative path when lib is in src folder, or add some paths to PATH env variable.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't really understand your first point. My module is called "common_test" is there something wrong with that? The complexities due to the multiple ways of importing are part of my problem here. I think I read that importing by module name was considered better practice than by relative or absolute path. Modifying an environment variable to allow code reuse of a  pip installed package hopefully is not required. Is there a simple example somewhere of how to structure python shared/common/utils code in a separate package and access it, which satisfies my requirements?

Comment: `site-packages\utils`, means your module name is `utils`. where's `common_test` after installed? maybe you need change `setup.py` to reflect the `common_test` package.

Comment: Ahh, ok, yes, I understand now. I have a directory called "utils" at the top level of my project., and yes, that appears as a directory in site-packages. I see you are pointing out that I have chosen the common name "utils" in what is effectively a global namespace, so this is bad practice. I agree. I will change that to something more unique. However, I don't think this will resolve my core issue.

Comment: i'm also a beginner of python. suggest learn the structure of popular projects, such as [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) and its [setup.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/setup.py)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, I had to make a few changes:

1. Delete the file

```
 src/__init__.py
```

2. Change my import statements to reflect the change above

As suggested by @Lei Yang, I also changed my module name to be something more specific not "utils" which could have a name collision in the site-packages\utils directory.